# How do I access an IP Camera Error (Camera / Model: Grundig / GCI-K1505B)?

Tags: c++, opencv, video, ip-camera

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main(int, char**) {
    cv::VideoCapture vcap;
    cv::Mat image;

    // This works on a Grundig GCI-K1505B
    const std::string videoStreamAddress = "http://admin:1234@192.168.1.1/video.cgi?mjpeg";

    if(!vcap.open(videoStreamAddress)) {
        std::cout << "Error opening video stream or file" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    for(;;) {
        if(!vcap.read(image)) {
            std::cout << "No frame" << std::endl;
            cv::waitKey();
        }
        cv::imshow("Output Window", image);

        if(cv::waitKey(1) >= 0) break;
    }

}
```

**Error**

***** VIDEOINPUT LIBRARY - 0.1995 - TFW07 *****

warning: Error opening file (/build/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:779)
warning: http://admin:1234@192.168.1.1/video.cgi?mjpeg (/build/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:780)
Error opening video stream or file
Press  to close this window...

**GRUNDIG/Model:GCI-K1505B**

**Web Browser   MS Internet Explorer 6.0 (or higher), Firefox, Google Chrome, Safari
Access protection   By log-in and Password, IP filter, IEEE802.1x
Number of Clients   Up to 20 simultaneously
Video Compression   H.264 (MPEG-4Part 10/AVC), MJPEG
Video Resolution    Full HD 1080p/ SXGA/ HD 720p/ XGA/SVGA/ D1/ VGA/ CIF/ QCIF
Video Streaming Quad stream: 4xH.264 or 3xH.264+MJPEG Triple: 3xH.264 or 2xH.264+MJPEG Dual: 2xH.264 or H.264+MJPEG Single: H.264 or MJPEG
Frame Rate (Max@Resolution) 50fps@2MP, 25fps@2MP, 50fps@1,3MP, 25fps@1,3MP, etc.
Network Protocol    IPv4/v6, TCP/IP, UDP, RTP, RTSP, HTTP, HTTPS, DHCP, PPPoE, UPnP, SMTP, ICMP, IGMP, SNMP, IEEE802.1x, QoS, ONVIF, ARP**

Answer (score 0):

You have an ONVIF camera. ONVIF cameras have a rtsp url that can be used with opencv.

First you need to discovery you camera rtsp url. There are some aways to do that, you can try at the manual, or use some other software to give you that. I recommend the software onvif-device-tool ([link](https://www.lingodigit.com/onvif_nvc.html)) or the gsoap-onvif ([link](https://github.com/tonyhu/gsoap-onvif)), both works on Linux, look at your terminal, the rtsp url will be there

After you discovery you rtsp url I recommend you test it on vlc player ([link](http://www.videolan.org)), you can test using the menu option "opening network stream" or from command line:

```
vlc rtsp://your_url
```

Than use the rtsp url on you code, exemple:

```
    const std::string videoStreamAddress = "rtsp://10.0.0.105:554/user=admin_password=admin_channel=1_stream=0.sdp";
```

Also change your if to:

```
        if(cv::waitKey(15) == 27) break;
```

I tested with my camera, on Linux, and your code, with this modifications, is working for me.